# Not able to load nested Json data in BigQuery

Tags: json, nested, google-bigquery

I am trying to load nested json data in Big Query.

Here is the data and schema i am using..

scehma -->

[{"name":"kind","type":"string"},{"name":"fullName","type":"string"},{"name":"age","type":"integer"},{"name":"citiesLived","type":"record","fields":[{"name":"place","type":"string"},{"name":"numberOfYears","type":"integer"}]}]

data--> it is presnt in gc_data/load_data.json

{"kind": "person", "fullName": "John Doe", "age": 22, "citiesLived": [{ "place": "Seattle", "numberOfYears": 5}, {"place": "Stockholm", "numberOfYears": 6}]}
{"kind": "person", "fullName": "Jane Austen", "age": 24, "citiesLived": [{"place": "Los Angeles", "numberOfYears": 2}, {"place": "Tokyo", "numberOfYears": 2}]}

```
try {
    bigquery.datasets().insert(PROJECT_ID, dataset).execute();
} catch (IOException e) {
    System.out.println(e);
}

  // Set where you are importing from (i.e. the Google Cloud Storage paths).
  List<String> sources = new ArrayList<String>();
  sources.add("gs://gc_data/json_test_new_flat.json");
  loadConfig.setSourceUris(sources);
  loadConfig.setSourceFormat("NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON");
  //loadConfig.setFieldDelimiter("\n");

  // Describe the resulting table you are importing to:
  TableReference tableRef = new TableReference();
  tableRef.setDatasetId("myDataset");
  tableRef.setTableId("myTableJSONNew");
  tableRef.setProjectId(projectId);
  loadConfig.setDestinationTable(tableRef);

  List<TableFieldSchema> fields = new ArrayList<TableFieldSchema>();
  TableFieldSchema fieldKind = new TableFieldSchema();
  fieldKind.setName("kind");
  fieldKind.setType("STRING");
  TableFieldSchema fieldFullName = new TableFieldSchema();
  fieldFullName.setName("fullName");
  fieldFullName.setType("STRING");

  TableFieldSchema fieldAge = new TableFieldSchema();
  fieldAge.setName("age");
  fieldAge.setType("INTEGER");


  TableFieldSchema fieldJSON = new TableFieldSchema();
  fieldJSON.setName("citiesLived");
  fieldJSON.setType("RECORD");

  // this is for record
  List<TableFieldSchema> listOfJSonSchema = new ArrayList<TableFieldSchema>();
  TableFieldSchema fieldPlace = new TableFieldSchema();
  fieldPlace.setName("place");
  fieldPlace.setType("STRING");

  TableFieldSchema fieldnumberOfYears = new TableFieldSchema();
  fieldnumberOfYears.setName("numberOfYears");
  fieldnumberOfYears.setType("INTEGER");
  listOfJSonSchema.add(fieldPlace);
  listOfJSonSchema.add(fieldnumberOfYears);
  //



  fieldJSON.setFields(listOfJSonSchema);

  fields.add(fieldKind);
  fields.add(fieldFullName);
  fields.add(fieldAge);
  fields.add(fieldJSON);
  TableSchema schema = new TableSchema();
  schema.setFields(fields);  // This is to set delimiter

  loadConfig.setSchema(schema);

  Insert insert = bigquery.jobs().insert(projectId, job);
  insert.setProjectId(projectId);
  JobReference jobRef =  insert.execute().getJobReference();
  System.out.println(jobRef.toPrettyString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You've defined the citiesLived record, but it looks like you haven't indicated the record is repeatable, which is what your sample data indicates.  Try using setMode("REPEATED") on the citiesLived field.